# Android Nexus 10 emulator doesn't working

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

The emulator open but black screen showed and this message appear in AVD:

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
Failed to allocate memory: 8
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

This is the configuration of the emulator:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg7IR.jpg

Comment: have you checked `use Host GPU` in that `emulator settings`? Sometimes this cause a problem too. If so, uncheck it and try again

Answer (score 0):

Asked here: [Emulate Nexus 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052690/emulate-nexus-10)

And here [Preparing apps for the nexus 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956288/preparing-apps-for-the-nexus-10)

and in some other duplicate questions

Answer (score 0):

In file: `Users\.android\avd\.avd\config.ini` you should delate **MB** in line: `hw.ramSize=1024MB`

But for me much faster and better work [Genymotion emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/)